# How to make a history tasks algorithm?

Tags: java

I have a Bank Account where I perform tasks such as: make a deposit / withdraw. I need to create history which stores 10 last actions I made. (Say there is only one account in the whole bank).

As I think, there would be at least 2 classes: BankAccount and Actions;

```
class BankAccount {
   private Action performTask;    
   public class Action() {
      private int actIndex;
      private String[] act = new String[10];

      Action() {
        actIndex = -1;    
      }

      public void add(String title) {
        ++actIndex;
        act[actIndex] = title;
      }
   }

  public void deposit(){
    performTask.add("Deposit");
  }    
}
```

There could be mistakes, but still not getting a desired result. How can I achieve my desired results? Any ideas?

Comment: 1) don't nest these classes as you're currently doing. 2) I'd make Action an interface if possible.

Comment: I am working with nested classes now, and the exercise is to use it in such situation. EDIT: maybe I need to achieve this by creating aAction's objects? And also initialize a Action lastAct in my Bank account class. (?)

Comment: So, what is your desired result and what is the actual result?

Comment: No, I need to achieve algorithm to create a 10 last tasks history using nested class. (In my post it's only a structure from my thoughts)

Comment: @Ernusc I gave an example using a Queue, but if you want the last 10 operations in the order of latest ones....you can use a Stack, in the same way. Wait for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ACtion` class is abstract class. Which has two function:

- `doAction(int k)` which withdraw or deposit according to implementation
- `printAction()` which print the action which was performed

`DepositAction` and `WithdrawAction` are two implementation of the `Action` class.

`actionList` is a `Queue` which holds the last 10 transactions which were occurred.

`amount` is the the total amount which the current account holds and this the number on which the two classes `DepositAction` and `WithdrawAction` operate.

Hope this will help you.

```
public class BankAccount{
    private int amount;
    private Queue<Action> actionList=new LinkedList<Action>();

    public void withDraw(int k){
        Action a = new withdrawAction();
        a.doAction(k);
        if(actionList.size()<10){
            actionList.offer(a);
        }
        else{
            actionList.poll();
            actionList.offer(a);
        }
    }

    public void deposit(int k){
        Action a = new DepositAction();
        a.doAction(k);
        if(actionList.size()<10){
            actionList.offer(a);
        }
        else{
            actionList.poll();
            actionList.offer(a);
        }
    }

    abstract class Action{  
        String actionDesc=null;
         abstract void doAction(int k);
         abstract void printAction();
    }

    class DepositAction extends Action{
        @Override
        void doAction(int k) {
            amount=amount+k;
            actionDesc="Deposit: "+k;
        }
        @Override
        void printAction() {
            System.out.println(actionDesc);
        } 
    }

    class withdrawAction extends Action{
        @Override
        void doAction(int k) {
            if(amount-k<0){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            amount=amount-k;
            actionDesc="Withdraw: "+k;
        }
        @Override
        void printAction() {
            System.out.println(actionDesc);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well just an idea

you can maintain a `queue` of size 10.

The place where you perform withdraw and deposit operation, make changes to the queue as well to reflect the most recent action.